# Using SwiftMailer inside Restler class

Tags: php, class, swiftmailer, restler

Trying to figure out how to use SwiftMailer inside Restler. I think I may just be including it incorrectly.  Per the [SwiftMailer documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/including-the-files.html), all I need to do is include a single file via **require_once** and their autoloader does all the magic, but I keep getting Class not found errors. [Supposedly](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/72) Restler plays nice with other autoloaders.

I've tried the following code in a variety of different places in my restler files (placed the require_once in the index.php as well as inside the class with the rest of the code).

```
class Remind {
    function post($request_data=NULL) {
```

[*snip*]

```
        require_once('../../Swift/lib/swift_required.php');
        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();                        // Create the transport; use php mail
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);                         // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()                             // Create the message
        ->setPriority($priority)                                                // Give the message a priority, 1 through 5, 1 being the highest.
        ->setSubject($subject)                                              // Give the message a subject
        ->setFrom(array($from_email => $from_name))                          // Set the From address with an associative array
        ->setTo(array($to_email => $to_name))                                // Set the To addresses with an associative array
        ->setReadReceiptTo(SYS_EMAIL)                                          // Send read receipts to Support
        ->setBody('Here is the message itself')                            // Give it a body
        ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')        // And optionally an alternative body
        ;
    $result = $mailer->send($message);                                    // Send the message
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Swift_MailTransport' not found in /home/[snip]/public_html/[snip].php on line 63
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar desire, to include Swift Mailer inside another class.  The solution was to include the swift_required.php outside the wrapper class, then create a class extended by Swift_Mailer.  In it you can reference the Swift_Message class:

```
require 'path/to/swift_mailer/library/lib/swift_required.php';

class Remind extends Swift_Mailer {
    function post($request_data=NULL) {
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()
    ->setHost('host')
    ->setPort('port')
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setPassword('password')

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setPriority($priority)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom(array($from_email => $from_name))
            ->setTo(array($to_email => $to_name))
            ->setReadReceiptTo(SYS_EMAIL)
            ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
            ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')
        ;
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Restler 3 RC4 (currently available in v3 branch) you can use composer's autoloader.

Use the following composer.json to and install both Restler and SwifftMailer

```
{
    "require" : {
        "luracast/restler" : "3.x-dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer" : "4.1.7"
    }
}
```

Read about composer from http://getcomposer.org/

Comment: What if you are running this on a shared hosting provider?

Comment: You can run composer on your development machine and upload all the resulting files. Most of the time this is what we are doing

Answer (score 0):

```
//the autoloader is a the swiftmailer downloaded with composer
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class Remind {

private $transport;
private $message;

function post{
  // Create the Transport
    $this->transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport('host', port, 'ssl');
    $this->transport->setUsername('username');
    $this->transport->setPassword('password');

    /*
    You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail:

    // Sendmail
    $transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
    */

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($this->transport);

    // Create a message
    $this->message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'));
    $this->message->setFrom("test@test.com");
    $this->message->setTo(array("test@test.com" => "test"));
    $this->message->setBody('Here is the message itself');
    $mailer->send($this->message, $failedRecipients);
    echo "message sent";
    // Show failed recipients
    print_r($failedRecipients);
   }
}
```